# How to split a string without truncating words in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, regex, plsql

I have a table `Data` with a field `Note` that contains a long string. I would like to split the content of each of these string every 30 characters without truncating words. This means that if the split is going to truncate a word, it should split before that word and restart the split process from the next:

*Example using split each 7 char*

**Data**

```
--------------------------
| Id | Note              |
--------------------------
|  1 |I am dumb using SQL|
--------------------------
... more rows ...
--------------------------
```

**Result**

```
----------------
| Id | Note    |    
----------------
|  1 |I am     |
----------------
|  2 |dumb     |
----------------
|  3 |using    |
----------------
|  4 |SQL      |
----------------
```

Note how the first split happens: the first 7 chars are `I am du` because a split on the seventh is going to truncate the word `dumb`, the split is applied before and the result is `I am`.

Some code to replicate the example and my attempts to solve the problem:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (ID, NOTA);
INSERT INTO Data (ID, NOTA)
VALUES (10, 'NEL MEZZO DEL CAMMIN DI NOSTRA VITA MI RITROVAI IN UNA SELVA OSCURA');

SELECT 
ID, rownum AS rn
                ,trim(regexp_substr(NOTA,'.{1,60}( |$)',1,rownum)) AS SPLIT_NOTA
FROM Data  connect by rownum <= ceil(length(NOTA)/60)
```

Comment: did you try something? We do not solve homework task.

Comment: Of course I tried something... And no, it's not homework! I'll post some code to replicate the example and my attempt

Comment: what about if the word is longer then 7 chars?

Comment: The actual value length split would be 60 or 30 so it would be a rare exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are trying to get an example that handles multiple rows?

```
with tbl_source(id, txt) as (
  select 1, 'I am dumb using SQL'     from dual union all
  select 2, 'This is a test of row 2' from dual
),
tbl_main(id, rownbr, txt, txt_length) as (
select id, level as rownbr, trim(regexp_substr(txt,'.{1,7}( |$)',1,level)) as txt,
       length(trim(regexp_substr(txt,'.{1,7}( |$)',1,level))) txt_length
       from tbl_source
       connect by level <= ceil(length(txt)/7)+1
       and prior txt = txt
       and prior sys_guid() is not null 
)
select id, rownbr, txt, txt_length
from tbl_main
where txt is not null
order by id, rownbr;
```

Output:

```
        ID     ROWNBR TXT                     TXT_LENGTH
---------- ---------- ----------------------- ----------
         1          1 I am                             4
         1          2 dumb                             4
         1          3 using                            5
         1          4 SQL                              3
         2          1 This is                          7
         2          2 a test                           6
         2          3 of row                           6
         2          4 2                                1

8 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you would not like to cut longer words:

```
([^ ]{1}.{1,6}(?= ))|([^\n ]{1,})
```

Explanation of main groups of the regex:

`([^ ]{1}.{1,6}(?= ))` - one not-space followed by up to 6 chars which have a space after them (positive lookahead).

`([^\n ]{1,})` - one or more not-spaces, not-newlines. This part of the regex is responsible for covering longer words than 7 (or 30) chars and covering last word from the string.

You should replace `6` with `n-1` where `n` is the number of chars which may fit without truncating (in your case - 7 or 30). I have developed this regex using Notepad++ and I can not promise that it would work in your environment.

Comment: Oracle's regex does not support lookahead/lookbehind assertions.